# How to get JQuery Autocomplete to work with categories?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have an input field like:

```
<input id="categoria" name="nome_categoria" type="text" required minlength="2">
```

In JS, I've got (from Jquery website):

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
  var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
      ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      });
    }
});
```

I'm getting the data from PHP, in valid JSON format:

```
[{"Label":"Vendas","Category":"Recebimentos"},{"Label":"Fornecedores","Category":"Pagamentos"}]
```

I've tried several things but none is making autocomplete to work with categories:

```
$('#categoria').catcomplete({
       delay:0,
       source: 'search.php',   
});
```

I can see in the "Network" tab in Chrome Dev tools, that the letters I type in the input field are being searched, but nothing is displayed in the input form, so I tried:

```
$('#categoria').autocomplete({
    minLength:1,
    source: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
         url: 'search.php', 
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { palavra : request.term },
         success: function(result) {
              response(result);
         }
       });
   }
});
```

This second approach is filtering the JSON returned from PHP with the letters typed in the input, it seems OK but I get an empty dropdown box in the field.

I've seen similar questions, including [this one](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/new-autocomplete-and-remote-datasource) but so far, nothing. How do I get autocomplete with categories?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try doing it via `source: [{label: 'label1', value: 'value1', category:'category1'}, {label: 'label2', value: 'value2', category:'category2'}, {label: 'label3', value: 'value3', category:'category3'}]` , this will help you avoid `$.post` call and see if it works with hard-coded data initially. Once ready, replace it with the function.

Comment: With a local data source, the 1st approach works without problems, just like in the example at: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution above works well, if instead of "Label", I use "label" and instead of "Category" I use "category".